# How does middle rounds of AES encryption work in Go runtime?

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography, runtime, aes

I learn how AES`s implementation work in Go and I do not understand how middle rounds work while encrypt block in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/aes/block.go:

```
// Middle rounds shuffle using tables.
// Number of rounds is set by length of expanded key.
nr := len(xk)/4 - 2 // - 2: one above, one more below
k := 4
for r := 0; r < nr; r++ {
    t0 = xk[k+0] ^ te0[uint8(s0>>24)] ^ te1[uint8(s1>>16)] ^ te2[uint8(s2>>8)] ^ te3[uint8(s3)]
    t1 = xk[k+1] ^ te0[uint8(s1>>24)] ^ te1[uint8(s2>>16)] ^ te2[uint8(s3>>8)] ^ te3[uint8(s0)]
    t2 = xk[k+2] ^ te0[uint8(s2>>24)] ^ te1[uint8(s3>>16)] ^ te2[uint8(s0>>8)] ^ te3[uint8(s1)]
    t3 = xk[k+3] ^ te0[uint8(s3>>24)] ^ te1[uint8(s0>>16)] ^ te2[uint8(s1>>8)] ^ te3[uint8(s2)]
    k += 4
    s0, s1, s2, s3 = t0, t1, t2, t3
}
```

I understand that this code do SybButes, ShiftRows, MixColumns and AddRoundKey of AES, but I do not understand how this code do it by using 
"te0", "te1", "te2", "te3" arrays. It's precomputed arrays which are defined in https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/aes/const.go.

May someone explain to me how these arrays was precomputed? Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: The table driven implementation likely leaks information through side channels. On x86, ARMv8, POWER8 (and friends) you should use the built-in hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question in:

1. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19175/efficient-aes-use-of-t-tables
2. [Generating AES (AES-256) Lookup Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094722/generating-aes-aes-256-lookup-tables)
3. https://golang.org/src/crypto/aes/aes_test.go